# EWF Issue When Imaging Windows XP Embedded Using Ghost

Tags: partitioning, disk-image, embedded, norton-ghost, windows-xp-embedded

On an HP Thin client, I have Windows XP Embedded 6.0, and I am using an EWF ([Enhanced Write Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838511%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)).

I make a disk to disk copy with Norton Ghost 2003, copy the image onto a usb flash disk, and transfer it to another HP thin client. The problem is that the EWF function is disabled, I've tried to re-enable this function, but it's not working.

EWF creates its own partition/volume, usually during the First Boot Agent (FBA) process. I think this partition must be included in the disk image, but I'm not sure. Can anyone shed some light as to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are copying all partitions when you create the GHOST image? EWF seems to have one of its own as you note so you need to capture all partitions.

Does GHOST "see" all partitions when you are making the image?